# Angular hasClass returns true even though the class is not present

Tags: angularjs, class, testing, jasmine, ng-hide

In yet another exciting installment of "what are you doing, tbm?", I have a test that (admittedly was passing before [changes] but now) is failing due to an apparent class being present, despite all efforts to prove otherwise.

Context:

A list of entrants is shown, each of which can be rated or scored. Inside an entrant's div, related (by category) entrants are shown in summary. A summarized entrant's score is not shown until the entrant itself is rated via its own div. This test verifies this behaviour.

Test:

```
it('related items are hidden until scored', function() {

    expect(judgeService.entrants[2].rating.score).toBe(0);

    var other = angular.element(element.find('.competition')[0]);
    var score_container = other.find('div > div');
    expect(score_container.hasClass('ng-hide')).toBe(true);

    judgeService.entrants[2].rating.score = 3;
    scope.$digest();

    // We'll refer to this later
    console.log('HTML: ' + other.html());
    console.log('CLASS: ' + score_container.attr('class'));

    // failure here
    expect(score_container.hasClass('ng-hide')).toBe(false); 
});
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="competition"
            ng-repeat="other in item.related">
            <div>
                {{ other.name }}<br/>
                <!-- this becomes the div > div in the test -->
                <score-block item="other" ng-show="other.rating.score"></score-block>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Output:

```
LOG: 'HTML:
            <div class="ng-binding">
                Andres<br>
                <div class="ng-isolate-scope" ng-class="{error: vm.error}" item="other" ng-show="other.rating.score">
[ skippy bits ]'

LOG: 'CLASS: ng-isolate-scope'
```

So, yeah, the class IS NOT present on the element.. so why does hasClass() think it is?

[changes]

Per git bisect, the change that caused the test to start failing was in an unrelated directive. But even if the change was directly related, I fail to see how everybody but hasClass() reports the class as absent.

Update:

Digging through the jquery code (hasClass() uses jquery if installed) it appears that element.hasClass("foo") will return true if any of the child elements of element has the class "foo", even if element itself does not. WTF, jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is caused by the 'div > div' selector recursing from the parent element into a child which has the ng-hide class.

The fix:

```
var score_container = other.find('div > div').eq(0);
```